# How to extract cookies from a HTTPResponse using cookielib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, httpresponse

I'm trying to extract the cookies from a `HTTPResponse` using `cookielib.CookieJar.extract_cookies()`, but I keep getting an error saying that the response object doesn't have an `.info` attribute. I know it's more designed for pseudo-file objects like those returned by `urllib2.urlopen`, but what's the canonical way to extract cookies from a `HTTPResponse`? Here's what I've got:

```
def _make_request(self, loc, headers, data=None, retry=True):
    retries = 0
    max_retries = self._retry_max if retry else 1
    self._request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/')
    self._connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    try:
        while retries < max_retries:
            try:
                self._request.add_data(data)
                self._connection.request(self._request.get_method(), self._request.get_selector() + loc,
                                         self._request.get_data(), headers)
                resp = self._connection.getresponse()
                self._cookies.extract_cookies(resp, self._request) # problems!
                if len(self._cookies) > 0:
                    # do something
...
```

Thanks

Comment: mock response object like https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/cookies.py#L114

Answer (score -1):

Try to use key `set-cookie` to get cookies. Here is example for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()

url = 'http://www.example.com/login'   
body = {'USERNAME': 'foo', 'PASSWORD': 'bar'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))

headers = {'Cookie': response['set-cookie']}

url = 'http://www.example.com/home'   
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers)
```